# htaccess language conditional redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, regex-negation

I need to make a redirect in my htaccess, depending on the presence or not of the language code in the url.

Url structure should start with the domain followed by the language code and then, the specific page (as any regular site)

domain.com/**en**/section/subsection/

As you can see, the **/en/** is the language code, but there could be different language codes [/en/es/it/]

So rules should be as follows:

- language code must be present and it must be 2 characters long

if this rule is not matched, browser should be redirected to the default lang "/en/"

In my mind it is something like this... only in my mind ;)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([az]){2}/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex doesn't seem right and you can do this in `RewriteRule` itself:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. I know my regex was wrong hehehe, it was only to figure it out. Your approach seems to be a good start, but, since there are more possible language codes, it would be good it was dynamic, so I dont need to put them all. That is why I was thinking somethiing like [az]{2}, any idea?? Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, finally your approach worked, but had to add 2 things:
- a 301 redirect flag
- a condition to avoid all the files that shouldnt be redirected

@anubhava, with that it works excellent. I will mark your answer as the correct one, and will add the final code. If you want, you can update your answer with the final code, so it remains correct for other people.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Ok instead of negating all the file extensions we can also skip files/directories as in latest update. Pls check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @anubhava, finally this code worked like a charm.
Thanks!!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.(js|css|png|jpe?g|gif|eot|woff2?|ttf|otf|svg|json|txt|xml|html?|htc|ico|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|mp3|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|swf|fla|safariextz|svgz?|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|xpi)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```